# Importing page styling into a different Wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm playing around with a wordpress theme from the ground up and want to pull in a particular page's content into the home page along with any styling I made in the editor (line breaks, color changes, bolding, etc.).  As of right now, it just pulls the text with no line breaks or anything else.  Here's the code I'm using to pull in the page:

```
    <?php
  $home_page_post_id = 15;
  $home_page_post = get_post( $home_page_post_id, ARRAY_A );
  $content_home = $home_page_post['post_content'];
  echo $content_home;
?>
```

What in the world am I missing?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe query a post category and display your latest post... just to see if it pulls everything. Double check your css as well. Just blabbing here, I have not seen anything you are up to in there...